# ConstraintLayout issue with circleci on Android

Tags: android, circleci

I am having the following build failure on circleci for my android project :

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>     [Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.0-beta4, ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.0-beta4].
>     Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>     Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

I am using the following circle.yml for build:

```
test:
override:
    - (./gradlew assemble):
        timeout: 360

dependencies:
    pre:
  # Android SDK Platform 24
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-25" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-25"; fi
  # Android SDK Build-tools, revision 25.0.1
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.1" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-25.0.1"; fi
  # Android Support Repository, revision 40 / Local Maven repository for Support Libraries
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.1" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"; fi
  # Google Support Repository, revision 40 / Local Maven repository for Support Libraries
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.0.1" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository"; fi
  - mkdir $ANDROID_HOME/licenses; ls -l $ANDROID_HOME/licenses
  - cp --force licenses/* $ANDROID_HOME/licenses; ls -l $ANDROID_HOME/licenses


cache_directories:
  - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-25
  - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.1
  - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository
  - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository

override:
# Adding true flag because of this issue with ConstraintLayout https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212128
  - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies || true
machine:
    java:
        version: oraclejdk8
    environment:
        ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
```

What might be the cause of this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `android` is deprecated or being replaced with `sdkmanager` as a package manager. For example, in my case, `sdkmanager` has access(lists) to the ConstraintLayout and ConstraintLayout Solver packages, but `android` does not.

For more info on `sdkmanager`, visit [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

In my case, I also had to update the sdk tools using `android` in order to have `sdkmanager` installed. The install location is not in the `tools` folder, though, but `tools/bin`, so I also had to access `sdkmanager` directly, as it wasn't included in `$PATH` on my CI machine.

Applying all this to your case:

```
  # Android SDK Platform 24
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-25" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-25"; fi
  # Android SDK Build-tools, revision 25.0.1
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.1" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-25.0.1"; fi
  # Android Support Repository, revision 40 / Local Maven repository for Support Libraries
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/25.0.1" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"; fi
  # Google Support Repository, revision 40 / Local Maven repository for Support Libraries
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/10.0.1" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository"; fi

  # Android Tools latest (has sdkmanager)
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"; fi
  # ConstraintLayout
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.0-beta4" ]; then echo y | /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta4"; fi
  # ConstraintLayout Solver
  - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.0-beta4" ]; then echo y | /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-beta4"; fi
```